# virtual machine master to robotic armv7 node communication issues

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

running a virtual machine as the master and having trouble  getting rostopic to get data.

always asks if my messages are built.

Is there a way to confirm that they are built?

---

Edit: I noted my question was vague without details...

I  attempt

```
rostopic ech /turtle1/cmd_vel
```

Response:

```
ERROR: Cannot load message class for [geometry_msgs/Twist]. Are your messages built?
```

Some googling says I should be able to run `sudo netcat` from both directions, but I can only do it one way..... still working on it.....

if I run (on virtual Machine MASTER (lvbuser001-VirtualBox)): `sudo netcat -l 1234`

and run (on ARMv7 (chip)): `sudo netcat lvbuser001-VirtualBox 1234`

it works!

if I run (on ARMv7 (chip)): `sudo netcat -l 1234`

and run (on virtual Machine MASTER): `sudo netcat chip 1234`

it fails!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253427/virtual-machine-master-to-robotic-armv7-node-communication-issues/) by [w](https://answers.ros.org/users/29217/w/) on ROS Answers with karma: 99 on 2017-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure everything discussed in [wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup) works correctly.

From the test you describe it could be that:

1. your VM is using a NAT-ed network connection (essentially one-way traffic)
2. you don't have a working DNS for all involved hosts

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0